# Parallelization doesn't work with the foreach package

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, parallel-foreach

Using the foreach package, I was expecting the following line to run in about 10 seconds

```
system.time(foreach (i=1:5, .combine='c') %do% {Sys.sleep(2);i})
   user  system elapsed 
  0.053   0.011  10.012
```

and the following line to run in about 2 seconds

```
system.time(foreach (i=1:5, .combine='c') %dopar% {Sys.sleep(2);i})
   user  system elapsed 
  0.069   0.017  10.019
```

but it doesn't work.

I am on a Mac OSX, my machine has 16 processors and nothing heavy is currently running. I don't get any error or warning message.

Comment: Seems like there's nothing to parallelize here.  Your for loop states that all five loops run serially.

Comment: I felt like I misunderstood the [vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreach/vignettes/foreach.pdf). I thought that using %dopar% would cause whatever is within the foreach loop to run in parallel for each value of `i`. In the first paragraph of page 8 one can read: `To make any of the previous examples run in parallel, all you have to do is to replace %do% with %dopar%`. What is my mistake?

Comment: Did you get the warning message: "executing %dopar% sequentially: no parallel backend registered"?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to register a parallel backend.  Do something like

```
library(doParallel)
registerDoParallel(cores=4)
```